# ssl-client-cert is not forwarded by nginx ingress in aks

Tags: nginx, azure-aks

1. client sends ssl-client-cert in the header
2. the program processes this header fine in local, in aks it is also ok through service external ip address

AKS version 1.24.9
ingress version ingress-nginx-4.0.13

nginx ingress doesn't pass this header, tried several annotations in ingress, nothing work, no solution yet found on the web

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: optional_no_ca